# Why to include <meta charset=“” />?

Tags: html, encoding, meta-tags

I mean if a browser is already reading the HTML file and is able to read the text `<meta charset=“” />` that means it already knows the encoding of the HTML file. So why is it needed to be specified **inside** the HTML file? Isn’t it redundant?

Is it because browser starts reading file using smallest charset, like ASCII, and it is subset of many charsets?

Comment: The text in the HTML can be Arabic or Danish or any other language using one of hundreds of charsets. If stored in ISO or UTF8 format, then the browser needs to know which character set to use. The server may or may not send the (correct) character set in the headers

Comment: PS: [charset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-charset) _This attribute declares the document's character encoding. If the attribute is present, its value must be an ASCII case-insensitive match for the string "utf-8", because UTF-8 is the only valid encoding for HTML5 documents. <meta> elements which declare a character encoding must be located entirely within the first 1024 bytes of the document._

Comment: Note that the `<meta>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob On W3.org [the example code](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations) uses the closing slash.

Comment: @onkarruikar Read the specification, not online articles for guidance. I've caught a W3C member doing this before and he acknowledged his error and corrected it. I will do the same with this one.

Comment: @onkarruikar Done. It's on the todo list to get fixed. They pointed out that the article is also seven years old and was probably anticipating the switch to XHTML instead of HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

> For a web page, the original idea was that the web server would return a similar Content-Type http header along with the web page itself — not in the HTML itself, but as one of the response headers that are sent before the HTML page.
>
> This causes problems. Suppose you have a big web server with lots of sites and hundreds of pages contributed by lots of people in lots of different languages and all using whatever encoding their copy of Microsoft FrontPage saw fit to generate. The web server itself wouldn’t really know what encoding each file was written in, so it couldn’t send the Content-Type header.
>
> It would be convenient if you could put the Content-Type of the HTML file right in the HTML file itself, using some kind of special tag. Of course this drove purists crazy… how can you read the HTML file until you know what encoding it’s in?! Luckily, almost every encoding in common use does the same thing with characters between 32 and 127, so you can always get this far on the HTML page without starting to use funny letters:
>
> ```
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
> ```
>
> But that meta tag really has to be the very first thing in the  section because as soon as the web browser sees this tag it’s going to stop parsing the page and start over after reinterpreting the whole page using the encoding you specified.

See also [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations):

> Always declare the encoding of your document using a meta element with a charset attribute, or using the http-equiv and content attributes (called a pragma directive). The declaration should fit completely within the first 1024 bytes at the start of the file, so it's best to put it immediately after the opening head tag.

So yes. The entire premise is that until the HTML parser of your browser reads that meta tag, there should not be any bytes that can be ambiguously interpreted as other bytes; the entire text shown including the charset attribute value ("utf-8") fits into the ASCII encoding.

From Joel's article:

> Internet Explorer actually does something quite interesting: it tries to guess, based on the frequency in which various bytes appear in typical text in typical encodings of various languages, what language and encoding was used. Because the various old 8 bit code pages tended to put their national letters in different ranges between 128 and 255, and because every human language has a different characteristic histogram of letter usage, this actually has a chance of working.

The average HTML parser goes like this:

1. Is there a Content-Type response header with a charset parameter? Use that to decode the bytes of the received content into a string.
2. Start reading the HTML as ASCII (or UTF-8). Is there a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type">` header with a usable charset? Use that.
3. Start parsing the bytes and use heuristics to determine the most likely encoding used.

Answer (score 1):

It is an obsolete tag, but the reason: we have ISO 646 (since 1967) which defines a standard set of characters. ASCII specifies the few optional characters on ISO 646, so ISO 646 is the mother of most of encodings.

Note: most systems are based on this standard, ev. using the *extension* ISO 2022, where you can encode 7-bit and 8-bit characters with few different encodings (e.g. used for Asian character set, where we need more then 256 characters). In any case, the start of a text is compatible with ISO 646. Then control sequences may change the meaning.

So browser can read most of ASCII data (really ISO 646, ISO 2022), and detect exactly how to interpret all other characters.

On Western languages, you get mostly ASCII on lower codes (until 127), but how to interpret the higher codes depends on language (Nordic characters, Western accented characters, Greek characters, etc.). And there are various encoding, which cannot be really detected without explicit specification.

Note: this method fails on few encodings, e.g. multibytes, like UCS-2, UTF-16, UTF-32, but W3C had some methods to detect it: the header should be mostly ASCII charset, so we should have a lot of 00 characters. EBCDIC and other encodings not based on ISO 646 (or ASCII) were already seldom. In principle you can check for some byte strings, but I do not know if browser did it.

In short: with heuristic (and ISO 646) you can guess on how to read ASCII charset, but to know how to interpret "special characters", e.g. accented characters, we must have more information, given by META or by HTTP header. Note: this works also with many Asian encoding (ISO 2022 based)

Why META? It is about control. HTTP header often required webmaster intervention, but with META the author of a page could override the encoding. (e.g. writing static pages, now most dynamic page generators can override HTTP headers).

Comment: The [meta tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) is NOT obsolete!

Comment: @Rob: ok I was imprecise: *charset tag in meta element*, and not officially obsolete, but we allows just UTF-8. (BTW: meta is an element, not a tag, but I think we got the meaning)

Comment: Yes, it's an element, but you called it a tag in your opening sentence so I stuck with that. I actually originally wrote element but changed it for that reason.